# Blackberry screen navigation

Tags: multithreading, blackberry, runnable, invokelater

I have a Screen name  **DownloaderScreen** when the screen start it will start download some file and when download is complete it will go forward to next screen autometically. I using the following code.

```
public DownloaderScreen() {
        super(NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | USE_ALL_HEIGHT
                | USE_ALL_WIDTH);

        this.application = UiApplication.getUiApplication();
        HorizontalFieldManager outerBlock = new HorizontalFieldManager(USE_ALL_HEIGHT);
        VerticalFieldManager innerBlock = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH | FIELD_VCENTER);
        innerBlock.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);
        outerBlock.setBackground(BackgroundFactory
                .createBitmapBackground(LangValue.dlBgimg));
        outerBlock.add(innerBlock);
        add(outerBlock);

        phraseHelper = new PhraseHelper();
        final String[][] phraseList = phraseHelper.getDownloadList();

        gaugeField = new GaugeField("Downloading  ", 0, phraseList.length, 0, GaugeField.PERCENT); 
        innerBlock.add(gaugeField);

        Thread dlTread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                startDownload(phraseList);
            }
        };
        dlTread.start();

    }

private void startDownload(String[][] phraseList){

        if(phraseList.length!=0){

            for(int i=0; i < phraseList.length ; i++){//
               gaugeField.setValue(i);
               // code for download 
            }
        }
        goToNext();
    }

private void goToNext() {

final Screen currentScreen = application.getActiveScreen();  

    if (UiApplication.isEventDispatchThread()) {  
        application.popScreen(currentScreen);  
        application.pushScreen(new HomeScreen());  
        } else {  
            application.invokeLater(new Runnable() {  
                public void run() {  
                    application.popScreen(currentScreen);  
                    application.pushScreen(new HomeScreen());  
                }  
            });  
        }
}
```

The code is working fine and starts download files and when download is completed it is going forward to next screen. But when there is no file to download `phraseList` array length is zero, it is not going forward. What is problem in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GuageField doesn't like going from 0 to 0. When the length is zero, don't add GuageField.

Answer (score 1):

Change the code to

```
 if(phraseList.length!=0){

        for(int i=0; i < phraseList.length ; i++){//
           gaugeField.setValue(i);
           // code for download 
        }
        goToNext(); 

    }
    else{
         goToNext(); //if nothing to download, then it will goto the next screen.
        }
```